# Explain Code (if statement with arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

This code prints out the biggest temperature fluctuation of the array in two consecutive days.

But I don't really understand, what happens in the if statements.

Would someone please be so kind to explain it to me?

```
public class NurTests {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] temperature = { 12, 14, 9, 12, 15, 16, 15, 15, 11, 8, 13, 13, 15, 12 };

    int maxTempDiff = 0;
    int foundDay = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
        int newMaxDiff = 0;
        if ((i + 1) < temperature.length) {
            if (temperature[i] < temperature[i + 1]) {
                newMaxDiff = temperature[i + 1] - temperature[i];
            }
            if (temperature[i] >= temperature[i + 1]) {
                newMaxDiff = temperature[i] - temperature[i + 1];
            }
            if (maxTempDiff < newMaxDiff) {
                maxTempDiff = newMaxDiff;
                foundDay = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which if statement ? All of them ?

Comment: The best way to understand code like this is to step through it with your debugger, and examine all the variables after each line.

Comment: The second and third :)

Comment: The first and the second ifs are pretty confusing. I would use an absolute difference instead: `newMaxDiff = Math.abs(temperature[i + 1] - temperature[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added some comments - should help.

```
        // Make sure we don't access beyond the length of the array.
        if ((i + 1) < temperature.length) {
            // Is this temp less than the next one?
            if (temperature[i] < temperature[i + 1]) {
                // New max diff is next minus this.
                newMaxDiff = temperature[i + 1] - temperature[i];
            }
            // Is this temp greater than or equal to the next one?
            if (temperature[i] >= temperature[i + 1]) {
                // New max diff is this minus next.
                newMaxDiff = temperature[i] - temperature[i + 1];
            }
            // Is the new temp diff the greatest so far?
            if (maxTempDiff < newMaxDiff) {
                maxTempDiff = newMaxDiff;
                foundDay = i;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

@OldCurmudgeon answered the question already, but perhaps you could make use of some additional comments:

- the `if ((i + 1) < temperature.length)` can be eliminated by running the loop until `i < temperature.length-1`: this way `i+1` will be a valid index for the array all the time, and thus no check is necessary
- the first two indented `if`-s deal with temperature rise and drop, and for both kind of change they provide a positive number at the end. There is a mathematical function for that, [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value), [`Math.abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) in Java.

Combined together:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length - 1; i++) {
    int newMaxDiff = Math.abs(temperature[i] - temperature[i + 1]);
    if (maxTempDiff < newMaxDiff) {
        maxTempDiff = newMaxDiff;
        foundDay = i;
    }
}
```